# Does a query result has always the same metadata structure?

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

Let's take a simple query example found on elasticsearch [website](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/search-request-body.html):

```
GET /twitter/_search
{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

This return the following result:

```
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards":{
        "total" : 1,
        "successful" : 1,
        "skipped" : 0,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits":{
        "total" : 1,
        "max_score": 1.3862944,
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "twitter",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "0",
                "_score": 1.3862944,
                "_source" : {
                    "user" : "kimchy",
                    "message": "trying out Elasticsearch",
                    "date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
                    "likes" : 0
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Does the object properties of result data is always the same and then I can access to `_source` data by doing `response.hits.hits._source`. Or, do I need to always verify if each property of nested object exists:

```
if(response.hits && response.hits.hits && response.hits.hits._source) {
  //Do something
}
```

This question concerns also filters, aggregations, etc.

Any thought ?

Comment: Well, it depends on the different queries you're making, but yes the main skeleton is always the same.

Comment: yes the response you can assume that it will be always same(Success). The response will be different in case of error response. You can get only _source also https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-get.html#_source

Comment: @Kaushik I have already read about getting only _source but it seems to not be possible on a _search query. Right ?